# c++ Multidimensional array second row overwriting the first row

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I initially made this using 'for loops' in order to have user input value in each element of the multidimensional array but every time i execute it, the second row of the array overwrites the first one.

Here is the simplified version of the program.

SOURCE CODE:

[image: SRC IMG]

OUTPUT:

[image: OUTPUT IMG]

why does the second row overwrite the first row? i've tested this with multiple columns in the 'for loop' and each element from the second row overwrites the first.(even with multiple rows, the last row will overwrite the previous rows.)

How do i make it so that it doesn't overwrite the previous rows.

Comment: compile with all warnings enabled and treated as errors

Comment: You initialise `ArrayA` and yet `a` and `b` are not assigned any values.

Comment: thanks for replying, how do i do that, i use dev-c++ 5.11(this reply was for fjardon sry)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle lmao u are right, i replaced it with [3][1] and it worked. thanks(tried it to place another row here in my pc)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no value set in `int a,b`, `int ArrayA[a][b]` doesn't do whatever you expected it to do.
Give `a` and `b` some value, like `int a=2, b=2` or something, then it will work.

Comment: If one has `int a=2, b=2; int ArrayA[a][b];`, Then it is invalid C++ application, due to not following standard. Array indices must be compile-time constants (`constexpr`). Even though, such code, might be accepted by some compilers, due to an compiler extension.